# AJAX request using jQuery not posting form data

Tags: jquery, ajax, search

I'm trying to create a search form that posts the results queried from a MySQL database and I'm having trouble.  The query is running correctly but the information entered in my form field is not 'posting' into the php document and actually getting through

```
    <form name="IDsearchform" action="">
    <input class='required digits' type="text" value="" maxlength='8' minlength='8' name="term" id="search" />
    </form>


$(document).ready(function(){
    //show loading bar
    function showLoader(){
        $('.search-background').fadeIn(200);
    }
    //hide loading bar
    function hideLoader(){
        $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
        $('.search-background').fadeOut(200);
    };
    $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        showLoader();
        $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
        $("#content #sub_cont").load("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/searchID.php", hideLoader());
      }
      });     
    $(".searchBtn").click(function(){   
        //show the loading bar
        showLoader();
        $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);         
        $("#content #sub_cont").load("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/searchID.php", hideLoader());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the extra parameter in your call to $.load():

```
$("#content #sub_cont").load("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/searchID.php",
 {term:$(#search.value)}, hideLoader());
```

It's important to include the data, first of all. ;-) Second, you want to make sure that the data is an object so that jquery will do a POST instead of a GET.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: how do I make sure the data is an object?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is fist serialize the form data and then send it across. Otherwise jquery does not send the form data. This is what you need to do -

`$("#content #sub_cont").load("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/searchID.php",$("#IDsearchform").serialize(), hideLoader());`

This way your form post data is automatically send my jQuery.

Comment: if I could get this to work you would be a saint.  Everything seems fine it just returns "Not Found" I don't think the form data is going through still

Comment: what does firebug(check under Net->XHR tab) show you? is all your data going in? The above solution works for me.

Comment: ahh yes its saying GET not POST

Comment: sorry I should have added I am using a <div> as the submitbutton with the id for .click.  Does this form need to be using action="" & method="post" to work?

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  array_merge() [<a href='function.array-merge'>function.array-merge</a>]: Argument #2 is not an array in <b>/home//.com/temp/wp-content/themes/classic/searchID.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function  query_posts() in <b>/home//.com/temp/wp-content/themes/classic/searchID.php</b> on line <b>39</b><br />